# Load Image with Picasso from drawable using Path

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, picasso

What I'm trying to do is to load some images from drawable. In fact, I want to load the images like `R.drawable."string"` but unfortunately can't find a way to fit the string into it. Also, the string is loaded from a MySQL DB.

Here you can see the code.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Product> mProducts;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        mContext = context;
        mProducts = products;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product currentProduct = mProducts.get(position);
        String name = currentProduct.getName();
        String photo = currentProduct.getPhoto();
        double price = currentProduct.getPrice();

        holder.textViewName.setText(name);
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(price + "€");

        int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(photo, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());



        Picasso.get().load(id).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mProducts.size();
    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPrice;

        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried the `int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(photo, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());` that I found googling around, but doesn't seem to work...

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you trying to load images from your app's internal storage??

Comment: Yes, the images are already loaded in drawable folder

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677804/android-drawable-id-change-after-resources-modify

Comment: It's actually helpful. I'll check it out. Thank you @Praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest another approach instead of the one you need to use: you can have a conditional on what is returned from MySQL database, and return id (R.drawable.xx) accordingly like below:

```
int id;

if(photo.equals("foo")) {
    id = R.drawable.foo;

} else if(photo.equals("bla")) {
    id = R.drawable.bla;

} else {
    id = // default id
}

Picasso.get().load(id).into(holder.imageView);
```

So, this way each drawable has one particular mapping in database.

Comment: Can I follow this approach for like 100 images?

Comment: @Koti Regardless the performance, yes you can.. but you can make it in different ways like adding all drawables in an array, and only save the indices in database, so you now don't need to have the conditional .. Another point that you probably consider; adding 100 images in drawables for the purpose of switching among them is not that good; they could be in local storage or online repo

Comment: Ok, what's a different way that I could load my images using Picasso without putting them inside the drawables?

Comment: You can [load images from internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777206/loading-images-with-picasso-from-the-internal-storage) or from the internet with `Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);`